# In Amazon EC2, how do I make it run a python script when I “clone” that instance?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, amazon-ec2

Suppose I have a script in

```
/home/myuser/go.py
```

How do I run that script, when a new instance is booted?  (I'm used to using the point-and-click control panel Amazon has...)

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?  Let me know and I'll give you some steps.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP posted his original question, there's been a lot of work done with Ubuntu cloud-init.  If you're using an Ubuntu server on for EC2 (we use it almost exclusively in production), it's quite easy to specify a Python script to be executed when the instance is created.

Cloud-init supports mulit-part input, so you can insert both an upstart job and have it run a user-data script.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
go:3:once:/home/myuser/go.py
```

to /etc/inittab will make init execute go.py as root when the server hits runlevel 3.

That'll probably suffice for your needs.